# Linq to XML Converter

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Can somebody please help with the below place (where I am struggling to form the query)

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response id="1545346343">
 <date>2013-10-01 12:01:55.532999</date>
 <status>
        <current>open</current>
        <change_at>16:00:00</change_at>
 </status>
 <message>Market is open</message>
</response>
```

Class

```
public class MarketClockResponse
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    public string current { get; set; }
    public string change_at { get; set; }
}
```

My solution:

```
public void example3()
{
    var xElem = XElement.Load("test.xml");

    var myobject = xElem.Descendants("response").Select(
        x => new MarketClockResponse
        {
              //Struggling to proceed from here  
        });
}
```

Comment: Does the XML always contain only one `response` element?

Comment: What query? What's the question.

Comment: he doesn't know how to build the object from the xelement

Comment: Yes it always contains only 1 response tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select `response` elements from `response` element (which is root of your xml). Use this element directly instead:

```
var responseElement = XElement.Load(path_to_xml);
var statusElement = responseElement.Element("status");
var myobject = new MarketClockResponse
{
    response = new Response
    {
        Id = (string)responseElement.Attribute("id"),
        date = (string)responseElement.Element("date"),
        message = (string)responseElement.Element("message"),
        status = new Status
        {
            current = (string)statusElement.Element("current"),
            change_at = (string)statusElement.Element("change_at")
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myobject = xElem.Descendants("response").Select(
        x => new MarketClockResponse
        {
              response = new Response
             {
                Id = x.Attribute("id").Value,
                //.....
                //populate all the attributes
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would use `XDocument.Load` instead of `XElement.Load`, because your XML is a document, with declaration, etc.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");
```

Then, I'd set two local variables to avoid querying for the same thing more than once:

```
var resp = xDoc.Root;
var status = resp.Element("status");
```

And use them to get what you need:

```
var myobject = new MarketClockResponse
{
    response = new Response
    {
        Id = (string)resp.Attribute("id"),
        date = (string)resp.Element("date"),
        message = (string)resp.Element("message"),
        status = new Status
        {
            current = (string)status.Element("current"),
            change_at = (string)status.Element("change_at")
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for step by step instructions specially XDoc and XElement